# How to create a column with the corresponding data from other column

Tags: r

I have a column with all week days, and I would like to create another column classifying it as "day of the week" and "weekend". Anyone can help me?

Below find an example of what I wish to do:

| Week_day | Classification |
| --- | --- |
| Sunday | Weekend |
| Wednesday | Day of the week |
| Thursday | Day of the week |
| Saturday | Weekend |
| Monday | Day of the week |

Many thanks,

Wil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Week_day,
     "Sunday",
  "Wednesday",
   "Thursday",
   "Saturday",
     "Monday"
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   Week_day 
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 Sunday   
#> 2 Wednesday
#> 3 Thursday 
#> 4 Saturday 
#> 5 Monday

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Classification = if_else(Week_day %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"),
                                 "Weekend",
                                 "Day of the week"))

df2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   Week_day  Classification 
#>   <chr>     <chr>          
#> 1 Sunday    Weekend        
#> 2 Wednesday Day of the week
#> 3 Thursday  Day of the week
#> 4 Saturday  Weekend        
#> 5 Monday    Day of the week
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most optimized way to do this but I would create an array named "Weekend" for exemple. This array would contain "Sunday" and "Saturday".
Then, while adding your days into the left column, just check if that day is present in the "Weekend" array. If yes, then it's a weekend, if not, it's a day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You already got a perfect answer from @jared_mamrot but to be complete, here's an example using the `data.table` package

```
library (data.table)
# Create example data
data <- data.table( Week_day = c("Sunday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday", "Monday"))
# Create classification
data[, Classification := ifelse(Week_day %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), "Weekend", "Day of the week")]

> data
    Week_day  Classification
1:    Sunday         Weekend
2: Wednesday Day of the week
3:  Thursday Day of the week
4:  Saturday         Weekend
5:    Monday Day of the week
```